# Need a solution to filter products by multiple price ranges

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new in VueJS.
I have a list of products, and I want to filter those products by price range. so, I built a component (filter-sidebar) that's a sidebar containing filter types (price, brand.. etc) by radio buttons, I want to filter product prices, and the products with a selected price range will be displayed in the parent component.

&& If there's another better method to filter I will be happy :)

```
{
    "products":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name": "Apple Watch Series 5",
            "price": 339.99,
            "rating": 4,
            "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/1.3b312012.png",
            "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.",
            "brand": "apple"            },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name": "Apple iPhone 11 (64GB, Black)",
            "price": 669.99,
            "rating": 5,
            "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/2.1aba2cea.png",
            "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.",
            "brand": "apple"
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "name": "Apple iMac 27-inch",
            "price": 999.99,
            "rating": 4,
            "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/3.29c766f8.png",
            "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.",
            "brand": "apple"
        },
        {
            "id":4,
            "name": "OneOdio A71 Wired Headphones",
            "price": 49.99,
            "rating": 3,
            "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/4.73f34744.png",
            "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.",
            "brand": "apple"
        },
        {
            "id":5,
            "name": "Apple - MacBook Air® (Latest Model) - 13.3 Display - Silver",
            "price": 999.99,
            "rating": 4,
            "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/5.c5b188e5.png",
            "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.",
            "brand": "apple"
        },
        {
            "id":6,
            "name": "Switch Pro Controller",
            "price": 429.99,
            "rating": 3,
            "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/6.833c8951.png",
            "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.",
            "brand": "apple"
        },
        {
            "id":7,
            "name": "Google - Google Home - White/Slate fabric",
            "price": 129.29,
            "rating": 4,
            "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/1.3b312012.png",
            "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.",
            "brand": "google"
        },
```

Child Component (filter-sidebar):

```
<template>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h5 class="filter-heading">Filters</h5>
        <div class="sidebar-body">
          <h5 class="filter-title">Multi Range</h5>
          <div class="multi-range">
            <div class="multi-range-group">
              <label for="all">
                <input
                  id="all"
                  type="radio"
                  value="all"
                  name="price"
                  v-model="selectPrice"
                  class="custom-control-input"
                  @change="filterRangePrice()"
                  checked
                />
                All</label
              >
            </div>
            <div class="multi-range-group">
              <label for="10">
                <input
                  id="10"
                  type="radio"
                  value="10"
                  name="price"
                  v-model="selectPrice"
                  class="custom-control-input"
                  @change="filterRangePrice()"
                />
                &lt;= $10</label
              >
            </div>
            <div class="multi-range-group">
              <label for="10-100">
                <input
                  id="10-100"
                  type="radio"
                  value="10-100"
                  name="price"
                  v-model="selectPrice"
                  class="custom-control-input"
                  @change="filterRangePrice()"
                />
                $10 - $100</label
              >
            </div>
            <div class="multi-range-group">
              <label for="100-500">
                <input
                  id="100-500"
                  type="radio"
                  name="price"
                  class="custom-control-input"
                  value="100-500"
                  v-model="selectPrice"
                  @change="filterRangePrice()"
                />
                $100 - $500</label
              >
            </div>
            <div class="multi-range-group">
              <label for="500">
                <input
                  id="500"
                  type="radio"
                  class="custom-control-input"
                  value="500"
                  name="price"
                  v-model="selectPrice"
                  @change="filterRangePrice()"
                />
                &gt;= $500</label
              >
            </div>
          </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FilterSidebar",

  data() {
    return {
      selectPrice: null,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    filterRangePrice() {
      this.$emit("filterPrice", this.selectPrice);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Parent Component:

```
<template>

  <div>
    <filter-sidebar @filter-price="filterByPrice" />
  </div>

 <div class="grid-view" v-if="layout === 'grid'">
      <div
        v-for="prod of (handleRangePrice, filterProducts.slice(0, 7))"
        :key="prod.id"
        class="card"
      >
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="item-img">
            <a href="#">
              <img :src="prod.img" :alt="prod.name" class="product-image" />
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="item-rating">
            <ul>
              <li><span class="material-icons"> star </span></li>
              <li><span class="material-icons"> star </span></li>
              <li><span class="material-icons"> star </span></li>
              <li>
                <span class="material-icons-outlined"> star_border </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <h5 class="item-price">${{ prod.price }}</h5>
          <div class="item-details">
            <h4 class="item-title">{{ prod.name }}</h4>
            <p class="item-description">{{ prod.discription }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item-options">
          <a href="#" class="wishlist">
            <span class="material-icons-outlined"> favorite_border </span>
            <span>Wishist</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="addCart">
            <span class="material-icons-outlined"> shopping_cart </span>
            <span>View In Cart</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import FilterSidebar from "./FilterSidebar.vue";

export default {
  name: "search-bar",
  components: {
    FilterSidebar,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      productData: require("@/data/store-data.json"),
      selectedPrice: null,
     
    };
  },

  computed: {
    filterProducts: function () {
      let realProducts = this.productData.products;
      if (this.searchValue != "" && this.searchValue) {
        return realProducts.filter((prod) => {
          return prod.name
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.searchValue.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
      return realProducts;
    },

    // return filtered products by price
    handleRangePrice: function () {
      let allProducts = this.productData.products;
      if (this.selectedPrice) {
        switch (this.selectedPrice) {
          case "all":
            allProducts;
            break;

          case "10":
            allProducts = allProducts.filter((item) => {
              item.price <= this.selectedPrice;
            });
            break;

          case "10-100":
            allProducts = allProducts.filter((item) => {
              item.price <= 100 && item.price >= 10;
            });
            break;

          case "100-500":
            allProducts = allProducts.filter((item) => {
              item.price <= 500 && item.price >= 100;
            });
            break;

          case "500":
            allProducts = allProducts.filter((item) => {
              item.price >= this.selectedPrice;
            });
            break;
        }
      }
      return allProducts;
    },
},

 methods: {
    filterByPrice: function (price) {
      this.selectedPrice = price;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: `products.filter(prod => {return (rangeLow1 < prod.price && prod.price > rangeHigh1) || (rangeLow2 < prod.price && prod.price < rangeHighTwo) || ...;})`?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: if your range is between 100 and 500 or between 700 and 1000, you could do `products.filter(prod => (100 <= prod.price && prod.price <= 500) || (700 <= prod.price && prod.price <= 1000))`. That would return an array containing only the products that are either between 100 and 500 or between 700 and 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, please take a look:

```js
Vue.component('FilterSidebar', {
  template: `
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h5 class="filter-heading">Filters</h5>
    <div class="sidebar-body">
      <h5 class="filter-title">Multi Range</h5>
      <div class="multi-range">
        <div class="multi-range-group" v-for="range in ranges" :key="range.lbl">
          <label :for="range.lbl">
            <input :id="range.lbl" type="radio" :value="{min: range.min, max: range.max}"
              name="price" v-model="selectPrice" class="custom-control-input"
              @change="filterRangePrice" />
            {{range.lbl}}</label
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      selectPrice: {min: 0, max: 1000000},
      ranges: [{lbl: 'All', min: 0, max: 1000000}, {lbl: '<=$10', min: 0, max: 10}, {lbl: '$10 - $100', min: 10, max: 100}, {lbl: '$100 - $500', min: 100, max: 500}, {lbl: '>=500', min: 500, max: 1000000}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    filterRangePrice() {
      this.$emit("filter-price", this.selectPrice);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      productData: {"products":[{"id":1, "name": "Apple Watch Series 5", "price": 339.99, "rating": 4, "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/1.3b312012.png", "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.", "brand": "apple"}, {"id":2, "name": "Apple iPhone 11 (64GB, Black)", "price": 669.99, "rating": 5, "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/2.1aba2cea.png", "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.", "brand": "apple"}, {"id":3, "name": "Apple iMac 27-inch", "price": 999.99, "rating": 4, "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/3.29c766f8.png", "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.", "brand": "apple"}, {"id":4, "name": "OneOdio A71 Wired Headphones", "price": 49.99, "rating": 3, "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/4.73f34744.png", "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.", "brand": "apple"}, {"id":5, "name": "Apple - MacBook Air® (Latest Model) - 13.3 Display - Silver", "price": 999.99, "rating": 4, "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/5.c5b188e5.png", "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.", "brand": "apple"}, {"id":6, "name": "Switch Pro Controller", "price": 429.99, "rating": 3, "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/6.833c8951.png", "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.", "brand": "apple"}, {"id":7, "name": "Google - Google Home - White/Slate fabric", "price": 129.29, "rating": 4, "img": "https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/img/1.3b312012.png", "discription": "On Retina display that never sleeps, so it’s easy to see the time and other important information, without raising or tapping the display. New location features, from a built-in compass to current elevation, help users better navigate their day, while international emergency calling1 allows customers to call emergency services directly from Apple Watch in over 150 countries, even without iPhone nearby. Apple Watch Series 5 is available in a wider range of materials, including aluminium, stainless steel, ceramic and an all-new titanium.", "brand": "google"},]},
      selectedPrice: null,
      layout: 'grid', 
      filteredData: [],
      searchValue: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    filterByPrice(price) {
      this.selectedPrice = price
      if (this.selectedPrice) {
        this.filteredData =  this.productData.products.filter(item => 
          item.price >= price.min && item.price <= price.max
        );
      } else this.filteredData = this.productData.products
    },
    filterProducts() {
      if (this.searchValue != "" && this.searchValue) {
        this.filteredData = this.productData.products.filter((prod) => {
          return prod.name
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.searchValue.toLowerCase());
        });
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.filteredData = [...this.productData.products]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <input v-model="searchValue" @input="filterProducts" />
    <filter-sidebar @filter-price="filterByPrice"></filter-sidebar>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-view" v-if="layout === 'grid'">
    <div v-for="prod in filteredData" :key="prod.id" class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="item-img">
          <a href="#"><img :src="prod.img" :alt="prod.name" class="product-image" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-rating">
          <ul>
            <li><span class="material-icons"> star </span></li>
            <li><span class="material-icons"> star </span></li>
            <li><span class="material-icons"> star </span></li>
            <li>
              <span class="material-icons-outlined"> star_border </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h5 class="item-price">${{ prod.price }}</h5>
        <div class="item-details">
          <h4 class="item-title">{{ prod.name }}</h4>
          <p class="item-description">{{ prod.discription }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-options">
        <a href="#" class="wishlist">
          <span class="material-icons-outlined"> favorite_border </span>
          <span>Wishist</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="addCart">
          <span class="material-icons-outlined"> shopping_cart </span>
          <span>View In Cart</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, bro. it's working! But, I wonder if I'd use Vue 3, not Vue 2, and want to use computed properties instead of methods what should I change in the functions?

Comment: @Eslam Gohar hey mate, you are welcome. You can use it the same way in Vue3.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, friend. I appreciate your help ♥